# setPlaceholderText for QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

Without subclassing can I have in QComboBox text that will be shown where no selection was made, something like setPlaceholderText in QLineEdit?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327964/qcombox-how-to-set-hint-text-on-combo-box

Comment: In my window ctor this works: `comboBox->setCurrentIndex(-1);` then I see place holder which I pick in Qt Designer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

QComboBox does not have a placeholder text option but you can achieve this in two ways:

1. Add an item with your placeholder text as the first item in the
   combobox and handle the item selection to account for the extra
   item.
2. Use `myCombo->lineEdit()->setPlaceholderText("Some text");` But this
   will only work if your combobox is editable.

Comment: using QtDesigner doesn't work, option #2 does. Thx

Comment: One tiny thing I had to do to make option #2 work, is to do `setCurrentIndex(-1)`. Otherwise it was selecting one of the items by default, instead of showing the placeholder