# Show item in a QComboBox but not in its popup list

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

[image: Select product]

I have some code to use a combobox to show a list of products. I would like to show "Select product" in the combobox:

```py
products = ["Select product", "223", "51443" , "7335"]
```

but I do not want the user to be able to select the "Select product" item. I just want the user to know what this combobox is used for selecting the product, and I do not wish to use `QLabel` to identify it.

```py
page.comboBox.addItems(products)
page.comboBox.setPlaceHolderText("Please select")
page.comboBox.setGeometry(150, 30, 105, 40)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QComboBox - How to set hint text on combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327964/qcombobox-how-to-set-hint-text-on-combo-box)

Comment: @Frieder i tried using page.comboBox.lineEdit().setPlaceHolderText("Please select"); but it appears system mentions that object has no attribute of setplaceholdertext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An item in the popup list can be hidden like this:

```
self.combo.view().setRowHidden(0, True)
```

However, this still allows the hidden item to be selected using the keyboard or mouse-wheel. To prevent this, the hidden item can be disabled in a slot connected to the `activated` signal. This means that once a valid choice has been made, the message is never shown again. To get it back (e.g. when resetting the form), the item can simply be re-enabled.

Here is a basic demo that implements all that:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleReset)
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        products = ['Select product', '223', '51443' , '7335']
        self.combo.addItems(products)
        self.combo.view().setRowHidden(0, True)
        self.combo.activated.connect(self.showComboMessage)

    def showComboMessage(self, index=-1, enable=False):
        if index:
            self.combo.model().item(0).setEnabled(enable)

    def handleReset(self):
        self.showComboMessage(enable=True)
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('Combo Demo')
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 100, 75)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
page.comboBox.setMinimumContentsLength(30)
```

Comment: what does this function do? @U10-Forward

Comment: @hope  see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#minimumContentsLength-prop

Comment: I tried using the code but user would still be able to select  'select hour' @U10-Forward