# How to enable a button only when two comboboxes have been activated

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have two combo boxes, and this is my attempt to enable a button only when options in both boxes are selected.

However, when I select only one comboBox, the button will enable itself.

```
    if self.page2.comboBox2.activated and self.page2.comboBox.activated:
        self.page2.viewbutton.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.page2.viewbutton.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and what you get for `self.page2.comboBox2.activated and self.page2.comboBox.activated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work, because the `activated` attribute is a signal object, which will always evaluate to `True`. If you are using comboboxes like the ones in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58726091/984421), then you need to check the [current index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) to see whether the user has selected a valid option:

```
if (self.page2.comboBox2.currentIndex() > 0 and
    self.page2.comboBox.currentIndex() > 0):
    self.page2.viewbutton.setEnabled(True)
else:
    self.page2.viewbutton.setEnabled(False)
```

That is, if the current index is zero, the "Select product" message is still shown.